# AngularJS рендеринг партиала

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте, я не давно начала изучать AngularJS и возникла необходимость сделать некоторый рендеринг, мне понадобилось что бы при нажатии у продукта кнопки "Показать" не открывалась новая страница а рендерился темплейт "show" на уже открытой странице в самом низу.

**ProductController:**

```
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', 'Product', function($scope, Product) {
    $scope.products = Product.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';

    $scope.showProduct = function (productId) {
          $scope.product = Product.get({id: productId});
     };
}]);
```

**index.html**

Описание ссылки для рендеринга, для каждого продукта:

```
<a ng-click="showProduct({{product.id}})">Show</a>
```

И собственно говоря сам рендеринг show.html в index.html:

```
<div ng-include="'assets/angular/templates/products/show.html'"></div>
```

Проблема в том что возникает ошибка в браузере(Chrome):

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column
>   14 of the expression [showProduct({{product.id}})] starting at
>   [{product.id}})].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извиняюсь, проблему решил, нужно было убрать фигурные скобки, странно, я ожидал увидеть там id ну да ладно.
Как должно быть:

```
<a ng-click="showProduct(product.id)">Show</a>
```

Пояснение такого поведения(спасибо [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)):

> ng-click - является директивой. На момент выполнения директивы - {{}}
>   еще не раскрыты и вы видите соответствующее сообщение об ошибке
>   парсера.

Comment: там был бы id если бы _ng-click_ не был бы директивой принимающей выражение. На момент выполнения директивы - {{}} еще не раскрыты и вы видите соответствующее сообщение об ошибке парсера

Comment: Спасибо, так гораздо понятней!

Comment: Можете добавить это пояснение в свой ответ :-)